# Copy Paste dynamic range based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a program in VBA that looks for data from in one excel sheet and copies it over to another sheet to the next available line. The data range for copying varies but it will always start at A16: and can go down to J86, but the pasting functionality can go on for quite some time, so that portion of the code is fine.

Ideally I'd want the macro to stop pasting over to "Sheet3" once it reaches a line where an item in Column A contains the text string "N/A". Currently it copies and stops on empty rows, which still saves me a lot of time but does make the spreadsheet uncessarily large due to large number of N/As being copies over.

Note: I still need it to copy rows with N/A in them, like B17, but once it reaches a row where A contains the string "N/A" it should stop pasting them.

Edit: "N/A" is the literal string N/A within a cell, not the error value.

```
Sub persist()
    Dim r As Long, tgt As Long
    Dim dt As Variant, oNum As Variant, cName As Variant
    tgt = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For r = 16 To .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
            dt = .Range("A" & r).Value
            oNum = .Range("B" & r).Value
            cName = .Range("C" & r).Value
            If Not (IsError(dt)) Or Not (IsError(oNum)) Or Not (IsError(cName)) Then
                tgt = tgt + 1
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & tgt).Value = dt
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & tgt).Value = oNum
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & tgt).Value = cName
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it the literal string "N/A" or an `#N/A` error value?

Comment: `If dt = "N/A" Then Exit For` would exit the loop when the string "N/A" was found in ColA

Comment: @TimWilliams it's the literal string "N/A". At risk of sounding dumb, where would it go within the code block? Would I need to input it into another For loop? Thanks a ton!

Comment: I’d put Tim’s code right after setting the var “dt”.

Comment: It works! Big thanks to both of you!

Comment: Side Note: Since you're copying values one cell at a time, you could speed the macro up by a lot by using `Application.Calculation = XlCalculationManual` at the start, and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end, just before `End Sub`.

Comment: @Toddleson looks like it does work, i'll keep it on there. I should never really have to copy more than 70 rows so it was pretty lightning fast, but i'll always take another speed boost. thanks!